# How to navigate nested loops within Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to do something of the following nature

```
if(...){

}
elseif(...){
     if(...){

} 
     else{
...
}
}
else{
...
}
```

However, it seems that powershell does not like having both an if and and else statement within the elseif loop. Any workarounds for this? Thanks for your help! I am really new to Powershell

I have tried switch statements but they do not make sense for what I am trying to do

Comment: `else(something) {` is not a valid powershell syntax, its just `else {`

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. I meant else{

Comment: you need to clarify on what you mean to "not like" because now your code is perfectly valid

Comment: If you can format the indents on the open and close braces to nest properly in your code it would be a lot easier to read..

Comment: It's not a loop, just branching.

Comment: Use a proper editor like VScode. It will make your life a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer per se, but I tested the structure exactly as provided and it works just fine:

```powershell
function iftest($a, $b, $c) {
    if ($a) {
        '$a true. $b and $c not tested.'
    }
    elseif ($b) {
        if ($c) {
            '$a false. $b true. $c true.'
        }
        else {
            '$a false. $b true. $c false.'
        }
    }
    else {
        '$a false. $b false. $c not tested.'
    }
}

#    command                 #     output
iftest $true $false $false   #  $a true. $b and $c not tested.
iftest $false $false $false  #  $a false. $b false. $c not tested.
iftest $false $true $false   #  $a false. $b true. $c true.
iftest $false $true $true    #  $a false. $b true. $c false.
```

As noted by mclayton in the comments, formatting goes a long way toward making the structure clear.